# How to check if a new line is added or removed in a Edit Text?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyevent

I have an edit text. I am easily able to get the new line from the key event. But, what if the text exceeds and goes to the next line. And also when the user presses backspace, how to know when a line has been removed? How can I get all these motions in the edit text? Actually I want to add a animation to the edit text with expand and contract animation when a new line is added or removed. Any alternate answers are also welcome.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please try my solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479592/android-catch-new-line-break-on-multiline-edit-text

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TextWatcher to listen to number of lines in the EditText.

***Kotlin***

```
binding.notes.addTextChangedListener(object :TextWatcher{
        var linesCount = 0
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            if(linesCount< binding.notes.lineCount){
                Log.d("HomeFragment", "afterTextChanged: New line")

            }else if( linesCount > binding.notes.lineCount){
                Log.d("HomeFragment", "afterTextChanged: Line removed")

            }
            linesCount = binding.notes.lineCount
        }

    })
```

***Java***

```
EditText notes = findViewById(R.id.notes);
    notes.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        int linesCount = 0;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(linesCount< notes.getLineCount()){
                Log.d("HomeFragment", "afterTextChanged: New line");

            }else if( linesCount > notes.getLineCount()){
                Log.d("HomeFragment", "afterTextChanged: Line removed");

            }
            linesCount = notes.getLineCount();
        }
    });
```

Where `notes` is the EditText id.

After the text changes in the editText, you can check the number of lines changed after adding a character or not.

This will help you so far, but also can be improved.

Comment: thanks for the java code. I will try it out and then accept it.

Comment: it does not work as expected. When I add a line or remove it after a break, it works. But, if I keep the backspace key pressed down, it does not remove all the lines. ie. It does not com in the logs. And specially with animation I am using, it works very bad.

Comment: What do you mean by keep backspace key pressed down? \
Do you mean this behaviour happens when word(maybe line of text) removed when you hold the backspace?

Comment: um. yes. when you want to remove the entire text, we either do select all then delete it. In that way the lines don't decrease

Comment: If you select all the lines and press backspace. 
This will be considered as one line removed, or the log will be printed once.

Comment: then what is the solution for that? I really need that. Even telegram does that